# Java: Convert Arrays To List Exception

Tags: java, exception, collections, classcastexception

`Arrays` class contain a function to convert arrays into list.When i convert the array of `Integer` into `ArrayList` it will throw an exception.

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[]{2, 4, 3 , 9};
ArrayList<Integer> test = (ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(array);
```

The `Arrays.asList(array)` return a `List` of type `Integer`, when i convert the list of `Integer` to `ArrayList`, it will throw an exception

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

`ArrayList` implements the `List` interface, so why this throw an exception ?

When i try catch the object direct with `List` reference variable, this work fine.

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.asList` returns a customly defined interpretation of `List`, it isn't `java.util.ArrayList`, but an `AbstractList` that is fixed-sized.

You will need to wrap all of the content in a new list:

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: *"...but an `AbstractList` that cannot be modified."* There's nothing in the javadoc saying it's an `AbstractList`. All you know is that it's a `List`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm going based off the class' source code: [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#3361)

Comment: Java8: Source says it return an instance of an inner private ArrayList class which extends AbstractList.. private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements

Comment: @MarcoAcierno & Rogue: It doesn't matter what the source says, it matters what the contract says. The contract is the declaration and the doc, not the source of a particular implementation.

Comment: Despite what the documentation might state it isn't a modifiable collection that is returned. If you attempt to do work on it, you will have a runtime exception thrown.

Comment: @Rogue: It's not unmodifiable. It *is* fixed-size. But you can modify it (and doing so writes through to the underlying array). And that's documented, both that it's fixed-size and that setting an element writes through to the array. Example: http://ideone.com/HeVWeY

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that I wasn't aware of then and will update the answer for.

Answer (score 2):

[`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) doesn't return an `ArrayList<T>`, it returns a [*`List<T>`*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). You don't know anything about the implementation of the `List`, just that it adheres to the `List` contract, with the documented limitations (the `List` is fixed-size, so presumably doesn't implement the optional operations like [`List#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) that would change its size).

Answer (score 2):

`static <T> Array.asList` method returns a `List<T>`, not an `ArrayList<T>`. You cannot assume that the implementation is going to return an `ArrayList<T>` implementation of `List<T>` - that's why you are getting an exception.

The error indicates that the implementation returns an instance of an inner class defined in the `Arrays` class; the inner class is called `ArrayList` as well, but it has nothing to do with the `ArrayList<T>` defined in `java.utils`. A simple cast between the two will not work - if you must have a `java.util.ArrayList<T>`, you need to create it yourself from the `List<T>` returned by the `asList` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a new `ArrayList` with a `List` as parameter:

```
Integer[] ints = new Integer[]{2,4,3,9};
List<Integer> temp = Arrays.asList( ints );
ArrayList<Integer> testList = new ArrayList<Integer>(temp);
```